# Select date value in date row based on first non empty cells in lower rows in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, gantt-chart

I'm trying to pull the start dates of all tasks automatically to the date column of a gantt chart.

The date starts in I3 and the lower rows contain first non empty cell on the same column of the relevant date. My goal is not to write the date manually to the row.

I found a formula that works to pull only one date but I wasn't able to transform it to something that automatically

=QUERY(transpose(I3:BP4),"Select Col1 where Col2 is not null limit 1",0)

Here's the link to the doc: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JdFFDjFnR6XfLMje1Ri_dY4FTzZY5WMLs17-UdOILNY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: could you share a copy of your file ? a minimal example of it so we can work with?

Comment: @Marios thanks for looking into this. I added the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the range G4:G and then try in G4

```
={"Date"; ArrayFormula(query(split(trim(transpose(query(transpose(if(L5:AF="x", L4:AF4,)),,rows(A5:A)))), " "), "Select Col1 format Col1 'd/m'"))}
```

and see if that works?

[image: Example]

Comment: @serdarsalim: Most welcome. If the formula worked for you, please accept the answer as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Cheers, JPV

Comment: Hi @JPV actually one more thing. My original sheet I don't use the letter x in the table so the formula needs to work with any first value. I'm still trying to figure out how to replace the L5:AF="x" part with NOT ISBLANK but wasn't successful so far. Could you help?

Comment: Try L5:AF<>"" and see if that helps.

Comment: It does in my test doc, but in the original doc wrong dates are filtered to the column. I'm trying to fix it. Will update here once I know more

Comment: What I found out is that it works for only up to around 20 lines in the original doc. The doc has around 200. If I run the formula in this range, it puts filters random dates.

Comment: I think you'll have to adjust the range to   if(len(H5:AF), H4:AF4,). The original formula only starts in column L.

Comment: Even with doing that the formula will not function correctly the row count is more than 200. I'm not sure what causes the issue, for now to get the dates I added the formula twice which solves my issue for now. You've been a huge help thanks!

Comment: Strange, I tried it on well over 200 rows in this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fh1JEYq875AHE1FjckWoJtSu_mtxyiJdpVkvc_Eu9kY/edit#gid=0.